# opengl/es: How to resolve excessive smoothing or blurring?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, alpha, smoothing

I have some very detailed 3D data that for some reason is very clear and detailed on OpenGL, but on OpenGL ES 1.1, all the detail is lost. In fact the model looks like it is translucent plastic, it is so excessively smoothed. In the following image, in OpenGL, you would see hundreds of individual triangles clearly.

Comment: Can you post both images? It's hard to say from the image you posted because we don't know what to compare it to.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that impacts is the GLhint call.  You can impact these items:

```
 GL_FOG_HINT
 GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_HINT
 GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT
 GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT
 GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT
```

and you can set them to

```
GL_FASTEST, GL_NICEST, or GL_DONT_CARE
```

like this:

```
 glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_FASTEST);
```

you can also do

```
glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

and maybe mess with the blend functions.  This call would allow transparencies:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my normals were being ignored. I had not specified GL_NORMALIZE.